# Which has better sound output -- an iPhone 6s or an iPad Mini Retina (1st generation)

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio

I am moving to a new job in a Windows environment. Currently I have my Mac running to a [Schiit Modi](http://schiit.com/) via USB and then from the DAC into a receiver. At my new job, I will have to output sound from either an iPhone 6s or an iPad Mini Retina (1st generation). Between these two devices, does one have a better onboard DAC?

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 6s will definitely deliver better results.

> While I cannot speak of the iPhone 5's audio performance, there has
>   obviously been an improvement between the iPhone 4 to 6 with the
>   ability to play 24-bit audio. **The iPhone 6's DAC measures very well up
>   to the maximum 48kHz samplerate**.

[In-depth review](http://archimago.blogspot.de/2014/10/measurements-apple-iphone-4-iphone-6.html)

To compare it against the iPad mini, [just read some user complains](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/sound-quality-from-ipad-mini-headphone-out-not-as-good.1492605/) about Audio Quality.

Though, the iPhone 6 didn't play High-res sounds. If this changed to the 6s, I cannot tell. [This article from mashable](http://mashable.com/2014/09/26/iphone-6-hd-audio/#0IxFlVegNuqb) suggests to use the external [Lightning-to-USB adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009WHV3XA) to plug in your own DAC to enhance the audio quality.

What's a fair point to make is, when you connect an external DAC to your iPhone 6s, you will have with no doubt a supreme audio experience. I don't know with which headphones you will plug in, but I am assuming the hardware wouldn't be a downer, more so the MP3 or audio file itself.